# PHP: overlaying two strings

Tags: php, string

I have to deal with an old data format. Fields (all empty) of different lengths are filled with spaces accordingly.
So far I have to determine the length of the transferred field (number of spaces), possibly reduce new values to the field length or fill them up with spaces up to the field length:

```
$fieldLength = strlen($record[$field]);                    // count length of field
$value = substr($value, 0, $fieldLength);                  // truncates the value to the field length
$record[$field] = str_pad($value, $fieldLength, ' ');      // fills up with spaces
```

There has to be an easier (more elegant way) - right?

Comment: Why does there need to be an easier way? Those requirements aren't so simple that there would be built in functionality to facilitate it beyond what already exists.

Comment: If it is possible to use only one function or a shorter call instead of a three-line line, then I find that desirable. Comparable to the use of ternary operators instead of "if, than, else". If it doesn't get any shorter - okay, then that's the way it is. But that was my question

Comment: Perhaps you're using these three lines of code for every field and all you need is to create a custom function :-?

Comment: That is function coding. Question is not how to avoid reundant use

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you search for?

```
$data = '';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($value); $i++){
    $data[$i] = $record[$field][$i] ?: ' ';
}
```